# d3js column graph, change number of columns on click

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, transition, demo

I have a column graph which displays fuel usage over time.

The initial view is total by year (up to 10 columns).

When a year's column is clicked the view should switch to a monthly view (12 columns).
When a month's column is clicked the view should then switch to a daily view (28-31 columns).

I can get the chart to update the number of columns, and redraw the data.

My problem comes when I attempt to get the columns to shrink to 0, switch the data, then grow to their new values.

I can get the shrinking to work, however the transition to the new data is a little off. I feel like the 'grow' should be in a call-back, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Code & sample data: https://gist.github.com/3240275

(I don't currently have a live version to demo... sorry)

Answer (score 0):

When you have sequential transitions, every transition should have a delay of sum of durations of transitions before. Have you done that?
(sorry - i'm not able to access the link)